# Let $X$ be is a countable, compact $T_1$-space and $A \subseteq X$. Suppose $A \subseteq X$ is not compact.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be is a countable, compact $T_1$-space and   $A \subseteq X$.
Suppose  $A \subseteq X$  is not compact.

> Can we say:
>
> (1): "there is an infite **discrete** subset $F$ s.t **closed** in $A$."Why?
>
> (2): X is compact. so $F$  has **an accumulation** point in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since $A$ is $T_1$, $X$ is countably compact if and only if every countably infinite $F\subseteq A$ has an accumulation point in $A$. If $A$ is countable and not compact, then $A$ is not countably compact, so $A$ has an infinite subset $F$ without an accumulation point in $A$; clearly $F$ is closed and discrete.
2. In a compact space **every** infinite set has an accumulation point.

Comment: Which book can I see "In a compact space every infinite set has an accumulation point". Thanks.

Comment: @Alireza: In any decent undergraduate topology text it will be either a theorem or an exercise, but it’s also something that you ought to be able to prove easily if you intend to read research papers in topology. Suppose that $X$ is compact and $T_1$, and $D$ is a subset of $X$ with no accumulation point. Then $D$ is closed, so $D$ is compact. Moreover, no point of $D$ is an accumulation point of $D$, so each $x\in D$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap D=\{x\}$. Thus, $\{x\}$ is a relatively open subset of $D$, and $D$ is discrete. A discrete space is compact if and only if it’s finite.

Comment: If X is a  compact T1-space and A⊆X. Suppose A⊆X is not compact, won`t $A$ be countably compact?

Comment: @Alireza: Not in general, no. $A=[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ is a non-compact subset of the compact $T_1$ space $[0,1]$, and it’s certainly not countably compact; the same is true of $[0,1]\setminus A$.

Comment: compact spaces $X$ imply that is $X$ countably compact and $X$ is countably compact if and only if every countably infinite subset of $X$ has an accumulation point . so is it right" if $X$ is **compact**, then every  infinite subset of $X$ has an accumulation point"?

Comment: @Alireza: Yes. I proved it in my first comment.